# I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm stuck at my login, frozen screen

Tags: 16.04, boot, login, backup

So quickly, I did my research, and so far I couldn't find a fix. I've asked this question already on another site "https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/411944/ubuntu-16-04-stuck-at-login-screen". 
Basically a rundown of what has happened was that I might have accidentally unplugged my Ubuntu machine while it was powered on, and when I get to the login screen after booting it up and putting in my password for the encrypted hard drive, the mouse doesn't move, and I can't type, and it freezes. (However, it seems that when I unplug my USB wifi adapter I can see in the top, it goes off.)
I've had some problems, such as not being able to log in to the tty when I use my liveUSB. 
My other issue is that I've been able to get to the root terminal using shift during startup, but running commands like `sudo apt-get update` gives me some errors stating that it's a read-only filesystem.

I don't want to try and reinstall the system since I don't have any backup devices like external hard drives, and the last backups I did through google drive was a while ago, and I might not get all my newer files. I also have a semi-important window in Firefox that I could merely recover the tabs, but I wouldn't be able to do that without logging in or reinstalling ubuntu.

Any ideas?

If you need any extra information, then I'll try and get to you as soon as possible.

Answer (score 0):

After trying multiple options, my best bet was to do as follows.

1. Open "try ubuntu" on a liveUSB
2. Open the file manager and open my drive, insert password, and go to my /home directory.
3. For some reason, I couldn't just copy my /home folder to google drive, so I manually moved all my important files to a folder in the desktop.
4. Moved  the new backup folder to my google drive, and let it upload.
5. Check to make sure all my files are still there.
6. Reinstall Ubuntu
7. Download all my files back to my computer.